How do I have a note that is held then glissandos to another note in Noteflight?
I want to have a note that is held for 3 beats and then glissandos to another note, all while being held (no rests in between). I tried having a note that lasts for 3 beats tied to another note that glissandos to the other note, but the tie made it so that the first note immediately glissandoed to the other note. So then I tried having no tie in between the first two notes, but it made a small rest in between notes. How can I get the desired effect? See image below if you are confused.


FWIW, the tied version works as desired in MuseScore.

In NoteFlight, I tried using two overlapping voices — one with two tied notes, the other with two glissando notes. It didn't work. This is looking to be a limitation of NoteFlight, but I can't say that definitively. Have you tried asking any of the NoteFlight user groups?

@Aaron i will try that , thanks

Your writing is correct IMHO, and shows one of the many limitations of NoteFlight (which uses simplified concepts as reference, for good reasons considering its generic target, but still problematic for advanced requirements). I don't know the underlying aspects of their implementation, but if it works as I suspect (considering the whole duration of sustained notes exclusively based on their ties), fixing that may be quite difficult on their part.
